# Data Synchronization between mobile and webserver

Tags: iphone, ios, data-synchronization

How would you implement a data synchronization solution that ensures data on a mobile device and web server are in sync.

Comment: A Webservice of your choise with an interface where you send the timestamp of your last data, server checking if his data was modified after this and sending you an update or the complete data?

Comment: good...thats easy... But whats the most efficient way timestamping or any other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look to this tutorial ([part one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1) and [part two](http://www.raywenderlich.com/17927/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-2)), basically what they do is add a timestamp attribute storing the last modifications. It is developed to synchronize with the parse.com backend service but it is extendable to any backend.

Answer (score 2):

We use a Unix-Timestamp in our company for this. The Server is comunicating with us in json over tls and client is using [AsyncSocket](https://github.com/roustem/AsyncSocket). For Web-Server (https) you can take for example a REST-service and [ASIHTTP](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree) for client. But our solutions are used for client independent services, so if you have only access with IOS/OS X it's maybe easier to use other solutions for direct synchronization :)