# iOS Development - Best practices when using an online database

Tags: ios, database

I'm currently developing an iOS app and it needs to be able to access an online database and retrieve/ update information on it. I can do this easily with webpages through PHP and MySQL but I can't find the best practice for doing a similar thing with iOS.

Any tips, websites etc would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A common approach with iOS is building a web service to front the database access for you, and program your app to the interface provided by that web service.

Comment: other question, but similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193422/data-synchronization-between-mobile-and-webserver/16193895#16193895

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Yes, that's what I did - C# webservice.

Comment: Thanks Geo. Found parse.com through that link which looks perfect for what I want!

Comment: Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start